# Add columns for counts of variable from a column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pivot

In apache spark, I have dataframe that 'category' column always be 'a' or 'b'.

```
user_id | category
====================
1       | a
1       | a
1       | b
2       | a
2       | b
2       | b
```

I want to make column 'a' and column 'b' for count of them.
The result I want is the following.

```
user_id | a | b
===============
1       | 2 | 1
2       | 1 | 2
```

Comment: Check Count, group by and PIVOT ... it's easy query and you can do it, if you having trouble after trying, come back and i'll help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS a
       COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'b' THEN 1 END) AS b
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: With this solution, you need to know upfront what all the possible values of `category` are.

Comment: @DavidGriffin . . . The question is pretty clear:  "'category' always be 'a' or 'b'".

Answer (score 1):

This will do it without having to know `a` and `b` up front:

```
df.groupBy($"id").pivot("category").count().show
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
`df.groupBy($"id").pivot("category", ['a', 'b']).count().show()`
I use pivot method with list ['a', 'b'] for integrity.
"[reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-spark.html)" also help me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All.
For integrity, I used pivot method with list ['a', 'b'].

```
df.groupBy($"id").pivot("category", ['a', 'b']).count().show
```